# Why can't this geometry problem be uniquely solved with simultaneous equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, systems-of-equations

So, I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1qiKJfe_3w) video on Mind Your Decisions, which involves creating a square $ABCD$ with side length $1$, with a triangle $AEF$ inside it, with point $E$ lying on side $CD$ and point $F$ lying on side $BC$, and angle $\angle AEF$ being equal to $45^\circ$ and angle $\angle AFB$ being equal to $70^\circ$. Our goal is to work out the value of angle AEF. I'm describing the problem rather than including an image from the video because of copyright.

From geometry, we know that angle BAF is equal to 20 degrees, angle DAE is equal to 25 degrees, and angle AED is equal to 65 degrees. Mind Your Decisions then proceeds to solve the problem using clever geometrical tricks, but it occurred to me that you should also be able to solve it using simultaneous equations, since we'd have four variables and four equations, as follows:

Let angle AEF be w, angle AFE by x, angle FEC be y, and angle EFC by z, then we can derive the equations w + y = 115 and x + z = 110 by supplementary angles, and w + x = 135 and y + z = 90 by the law of the sums of angles in a triangle.

However, when I entered these values into Wolfram Alpha to be solved, I got the following answer, rather than a unique solution: x = 135 - w, y = 115 - w, and z = w - 25. Given the geometry of the problem, and that none of the angles can be negative or zero, this should be true for 25 < w < 115. However, in the video, Mind Your Decisions' geometric proof demonstrated that w = 65, and this is a unique solution.

Why has this occurred? Why can't simultaneous equations be used to derive a unique solution for this problem, when a unique solution exists?

Comment: Do you mean $\angle DAE=25^\circ$? Also, it would be nice to have it with $\LaTeX$ ;)

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Yes, thank you. It was a typo. Also, not sure how to use LaTeX.

Comment: You just have to set everything in `$`
 symbols. For instance, `$w+y=115$` will look like this: $w+y=115$. I have edited your first paragraph, so that you can see the difference. Hope it helps. Also, there is a really nice tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $y+z$ is just $$(w+y)+(x+z)-(w+x)=115^\circ+110^\circ-135^\circ=90^\circ$$ Thus, you do not have four independent equations, but do have for variables...

Answer (score 2):

Without going into too much detail, a system of (linear) equations may not have a unique solution if there is insufficient information. In your example, the system

$$\begin{cases}w+y=115^\circ\\
x+z=110^\circ\\
w+x=135^\circ\\
y+z=90^\circ\end{cases}$$

seems to be four equations, but the fourth can be derived from the other three, deeming the last equation useless. We say that they are *linearly dependent*. Explicitly:

$$y+z = (w+y)+(x+z)-(w+x)=115^\circ + 110^\circ-135^\circ = 90^\circ$$

In this derivation only the first three equations are used. Therefore the fourth gives no new information.

A simpler example would be the system

$$\begin{cases}x+y=5\\
2x+2y=10\end{cases}$$

This system does not have a unique solution either, but we have two equations with two unknowns. However the second can be derived from the first.

Comment: That's very interesting. Do you know why this occurs, as a result of the geometry?

Comment: Using angle sums, we can determine all the interior angles of the quadrilateral $AECF$. However, without extra information, we cannot determine the angles the sides form with a diagonal. Consider the angles formed by the diagonal and the sides of a square vs a rectangle. The angles get stretched, but the $4$ right angles stay the same. We would end up with a similar system of equations, with every sum equal to $90^\circ$, but that's all we know without extra information.

Comment: Are you saying that this occurs because I'm using the angles for two halves of quadrilateral $AECF$, the triangles $AEF$ and $CEF$, and that I'd need to use one of them along with either triangle $AEC$ or $AFC$, since they would correspond with the other line between $AECF$'s corners?

Comment: Since we already know $\angle AFC$ and $\angle AEC$, the measure of those angles would not help resolve the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I just did the math for the triangles, and you'd just get $w + y = 115$ for triangle $AEC$, so it's just a more complicated way of working out the same values as the complimentary angles along line $CD$ at point $E$.